# wordpress security and xmlrpc.php

Tags: wordpress, apache2

Looking through my site stats I'm noticing a bunch of hits on my wordpress/xmlrpc.php file.  It's not from me afaik, do I need to worry about something here, is there anyway to secure this?

I'm running multiple wordpress sites on the same apache2, and it's only one of them that this is happening to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the xmlrpc interface (pingbacks or blogging from external sources like android/iPhone), you can turn off this feature. Settings -> Writing -> XML-RPC

Comment: So could this just be pingbacks then?

Comment: i just looked and the XML-RPC was NOT enabled. Nothing to worry about then?

Comment: Nope, nothing to worry about. If the calls start adding up to the phase where they block or slow down wordpress, you could block them in the web server (probably a .htaccess modification)

Answer (score 0):

I installed "Windows Live Writer" on one of my very novice clients. It is good for posts.
It is very simple and does a good job.
It needs XML-RPC.

Answer (score 0):

I've got also hits on this `xmlrpc.php`. But I'm not even on Wordpress! That's clearly hackers who try different addresses to gain access via this php page.