# Stopping a WordPress XMLRPC.php Attack

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, simplexmlrpcserver

I am experiencing an XMLRPC Brute Force attack on my website that has been going for about 28 hours now. Every few seconds, 188.0.236.9 tries to plug a user-pass combination into my XMLRPC.php file. I conducted a whois on the ip, which didn't help much. The phone number listed was invalid (yes, I was stupid enough to call).

Anyway, I've blocked the IP itself (it is a single IP) as well as the entire IP range, with WordFence. I don't have access to my .htaccess file right now; I'm not at home.

[image]

Is my website adequately protected, or is this person's attack still capable of doing anything? He's still sending requests as we speak, and though I've blocked him, I can't tell if he's still getting through.

Forgive me; I'm still relatively new to all this. If my site is not adequately protected, what more can I do without access to my .htaccess file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wordpress security and xmlrpc.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622106/wordpress-security-and-xmlrpc-php)

Comment: @edhurtig The feature which solved that person's problem  has been removed in the most recent version of WP.

Comment: Then that accepted answer should be updated...

Comment: You should consider 
A) Disabling the XMLRPC api if you are not using it for anything. I updated the above linked answer and hopefully those edits will be accepted soon.
B) or using a service like CloudFlare to prevent attacks like this
C) Install BruteProtect (the folks that invented it at Parka are great) (Now bundled with JetPack and known as the "Protect" module). (This is what I use and it works great).

Comment: @edhurtig Thanks so much for your help. I will look into all of these things. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You may want to check this post on WordPress Stack Exchange [What is a best way to eliminate xmlrpc.php file from WordPress when you don't need it?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/219666/105480)

Answer (score -2):

```html
// Disable XML-RPC using hook in wordpress.

/*To disable XML-RPC methods that require authentication, use:*/

add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');

For more granular control over all XML-RPC methods and requests, see the ‘xmlrpc_methods’ and ‘xmlrpc_element_limit’ hooks.
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it